# Align switch label to the left side - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following markup:

```css
.custom-switch {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label {
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::before {
  top: 0.125rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  transition: background-color .15s ease-out;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::after {
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: .25rem;
  width: .875rem;
  height: .875rem;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: #adb5bd;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0.625rem);
  transform: translateX(0.625rem);
  box-shadow: -0.125rem 0 0.125rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="example-switch-custom4" name="example-switch-custom">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-switch-custom">Test</label>
</div>
```

The label is now on the right side, as seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5hWp.jpg , is there an easy way to move it on the left side? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to play with few `left` and `padding` spacing.

Check below snippet for desire result.

```css
.custom-switch {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label {
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::before {
  top: 0.125rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  transition: background-color .15s ease-out;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::after {
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: .25rem;
  width: .875rem;
  height: .875rem;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: #adb5bd;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0.625rem);
  transform: translateX(0.625rem);
  box-shadow: -0.125rem 0 0.125rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.custom-switch.left {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.custom-switch.left .custom-control-label {
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.custom-switch.left .custom-control-label::before {
  left: 2.25rem !important;
}

.custom-switch.left .custom-control-label::after {
  left: calc(2.25rem + 2px) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-switch-custom">Test</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="example-switch-custom4" name="example-switch-custom">

</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch left">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-switch-custom">Test</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="example-switch-custom4" name="example-switch-custom">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to do the trick. But any idea how to do this only for specific switches? I would like to maintain some of the switches label on the right side.

Comment: This is not a trick we just have to plan spacing as we need for design, and if you want it for specific switch then i will suggest you add the parent class and then do left and padding css using that particular class for those only.

Comment: I have updated the answer adding 2 switch one with parent class which will show on left.

Comment: Only one problem now, if the label text it a bit longer, it won't push the switch to the right side, so it will overlap https://i.ibb.co/wYRFBdY/labellong.jpg

Answer (score 0):

i think you can du this like this

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="" for="sw">Is extra block</label>
             <div class="custom-control custom-switch d-inline" id="sw">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="edit_extra_block" name="extra_block" value="">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit_extra_block"></label>
             </div>
        </div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="" for="sw">Is extra block</label>
                 <div class="custom-control custom-switch d-inline" id="sw">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="edit_extra_block" name="extra_block" value="">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit_extra_block"></label>
                 </div>
            </div>
```